# Get QgsLayoutItemMap from existing QPT Layout

Tags: pyqgis, cartography, layouts, python-3, mapcanvas

I created a QPT model with a map inside QGIS. The problem is when I try to select the map under pyQGIS :

```
qpt = QDomDocument()
qpt.setContent(content)
layout = QgsLayout(QgsProject().instance())
layout.loadFromTemplate(qpt, QgsReadWriteContext())
mapItem = layout.itemById('Map') # 'Map' is the name of the item map

mapCanvas = iface.mapCanvas()
mapItem.zoomToExtent(mapCanvas.extent())
```

It returns this error :

```
AttributeError: 'QgsLayoutItem' object has no attribute 'zoomToExtent'
```

I know there is a class `QgsLayoutItemMap` but I don't know how to get it from the QgsLayoutItem map.

And I have another question : in QGIS composer, there is a button when I select my Map called "Set to map canvas extent". What is the equivalent in python ? `mapItem.zoomToExtent(mapCanvas.extent())` and then `mapItem.refresh()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my question : there is one way to get existing `QgsLayoutItemMap` from opened QPT and it's not the simplest one. You need to ensure you have only one Map per Layout and you can get it with `QgsLayout.referenceMap()`.
The complete explanation is here :

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-QgsLayout-returns-different-types-on-different-platforms-td5365596.html

Apparently this is a bug of Windows' QGIS that doesn't happen under Linux. It seams there is no other way to do it in Python API QGIS 3.

EDIT : the second part of my question is always topical.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I've been having a similar problem, but made a little more complicated as I've got two maps in my layout, so I'm a little disappointed to see you answer. Since you posted your answer have you found any alternative solutions?

Otherwise, it's two years too late, but concerning the second part of your question :

"*in QGIS composer, there is a button when I select my Map called "Set to map canvas extent". What is the equivalent in python ?"*

I use the following set the map layout extent:

```
"""set the map extent from canvas"""
ms = QgsMapSettings()
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
rect = QgsRectangle(canvas.extent())
rect.scale(0.5)
ms.setExtent(rect)
carte.setExtent(rect)

"""refresh map"""
carte.refresh
```